# Consider the maps $g,h: S^1 \to S^1$ given $g(z) = z^n$ and $h(z) = 1/z^n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Compute the induced homomorphisms $g_{*}, h_{*}$ of the infinite cyclic group $\pi_1 (S^1,b_0)$ into itself. (Here we represent $S^1$ as the set of complex numbers $z$ of absolute value 1).

When we have a continous function $h: X \to Y$  such that $h(x_0)=y_0$, for some $x_0 \in X, y_0 \in Y$. ($h:(X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0)$). Then $h$ induces a homomorphism $h_{*}: \pi_1 (X,x_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ by the equation $h_{*}([f]) = [h \circ f].$

How can I show that $h$ and $g$ are continous? I also must find a generator of $\pi_1 (S^1,b_0)$, right ? Once I get $[f]$ a generator of $\pi_1 (S^1,b_0)$ I can compute $g_{*}([f]) = [g \circ f]$. I don't know how to finish it.

Ps: I took it from Munkres, and there is a hint: $(\cos \theta +  i \sin \theta)^n = \cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta$. But I don't know what to do with this either.

Comment: The generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$ is the identity, and $g$ sends the identity to the map that winds around $n$-times around the origin, which is (homotopic to) $n$ times the identity. For the other, it is $-n$ times the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These maps are continuous because they are complex differentiable (the derivative of $z^n$ being $nz^{n-1}$) and this implies continuity.

Now $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ is infinite cyclic, generated by the identity (which is a loop $­\mathit{id}:S^1 \to S^1$). The induced map $g_*:\pi_1(S^1,1) \to \pi_1(S^1,1)$ is entirely determined by where it sends the positive generator, so we need just compute the winding number of $g_*([\mathit{id}]) = [g \circ \mathit{id}] = [g]$. Let $p:\mathbb{R} \to S^1$ denote the universal cover. It will be more convenient to treat $g$ as a map $[0,1] \to S^1$ with $$g(\theta) = (\cos2\pi\theta + i\sin2\pi\theta)^n.$$ This $g$ lifts to a path $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(\theta) = n\theta$, because $$(p\circ f)(\theta)= p(n\theta) =
 \cos(2\pi n\theta)+ i\sin(2\pi n\theta) = (\cos 2\pi\theta +i\sin2\pi\theta)^n =  g(\theta).$$

This shows that $[g]$ corresponds to $n$ via the isomorphism $\pi_1(S^1,1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, the induced homomorphism $$\mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(S^1,1) \xrightarrow{g_*} \pi_1(S^1,1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$$ is just multiplication by $n$. The argument for $h$ is identical.

Comment: You did just for $\pi_1 (S^1,1)$ because $S^1$ is path conneted? then $\pi_1 (S^1,x) \cong \pi_1 (S^1,y)$, for all $x,y \in S^1$?
I don't see why $id$ is a generated of $\pi_1 (S^1,1)$. Can you explain it?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $1$ is a convenient basepoint (and the one Munkres uses) but in the end it doesn't matter because the circle is path-connected. I'd suggest you review the proof of the theorem $\pi_1(S^1,1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$; the number associated to a homotopy class of a loop corresponds to the endpoint of any lift of that loop in the universal cover $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, the function $f(x) = x$ lifts the identity loop, and its endpoint is $1$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. When you say identity loop, it means the function $[0,1] \to S^1$ given by $t = e^{2 \pi t i}$. Thank you!

Comment: @JeanGeovane Yes, exactly! And viewed as a map $S^1 \to S^1$, it is, well, the identity :-P